# Need to remove everything that is after a letter with PHP

Tags: php, string

I have this link: `http://www.youtube.com/e/fIL7Nnlw1LI&feature=related`

I need a way in PHP to completely remove everything that is after EACH `&` in the link.

So it will become : `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fIL7Nnlw1LI`

Attention it could have more than one `&`

Everything after EACH &, & included, must be deleted from the string

How can I do it in PHP?

Comment: "After each" doesn't make sense. Do you mean "after the first occurrence of"?

Comment: No I mean what I said. The link could be also youtube.com/e/fIL7Nnlw1LI&feature=related&etc=etc&that=that&blah=blah. So after any &

Comment: "After any" also doesn't make sense -- you have to tell us where you want to cut the string! Do you want to *split* it into a collection of pieces separated by `&`, or do you just want the initial part before the first `&`, or what?

Comment: When you remove **everything** after the first & you are removing everything after the other &s too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this ::

```
$var = "http://www.youtube.com/e/fIL7Nnlw1LI&feature=related";

$url = explode("&", $var);
$url = $url[0]; //URL is now what you want, the part before First "&"
```

Answer (score 3):

As I wrote in rpevious your question you can use this 1-line script:

```
$str = strtok($str,'&');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can combine `strpos` with `substr`:

```
$spos = strpos($s, "&");
$initial_string = $spos ? substr($s, 0, $spos) : $s;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$url = "http://www.youtube.com/e/fIL7Nnlw1LI&feature=related";
$ampPos = strpos($var, '&');
if ($ampPos !== false)
{
   $url = substr($url, 0, $ampPos);
}
```

Don't use explode, regexp or any other greedy algorithm, it's a waste of resources.

EDIT (Added performance information):

In the preg_match documentation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Tested explode myself with the following code:

```
$url        = "http://www.youtube.com/e/fIL7Nnlw1LI&feature=related&bla=foo&test=bar";

$time1      = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++)
{
    explode("&", $url);
    $url    = $url[0];
}
$time2      = microtime(true);
echo ($time2 - $time1) . "\n";

$time1      = microtime(true);
for ($i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++)
{
    $ampPos = strpos($url, "&");
    if ($ampPos !== false)
        $url = substr($url, 0, $ampPos);

}
$time2      = microtime(true);
echo ($time2 - $time1) . "\n";
```

Gave the following result:

```
2.47602891922
2.0289251804352
```

Comment: You're right, I should have added that. Adding it in now! Thanks.

Comment: You can write this: if ( ! $ampPos = strpos($var, '&') ) { much cleaner.

Comment: That's another discussion, which I don't think this is the appropriate place for.

Comment: can you try to bench my answer too?

Comment: @Jitamaro it's not eqiualent(for integer 0)

Comment: 1.9984130859375, and also works when no & is found :) Yours is the best!

Comment: I don't think $url = $url [ 0 ] should be included in the benchmark. Can you try array_shift and list (), please?

Comment: You are free to test it; the code is right there, no copyright on it. Please let us know what you find :)

Comment: Alright, how about this then:

3.7675800323486 (array_shift)
2.1949717998505 (list)

Tested with

$url = explode("&", $url);
$url = array_shift($url);

and

list($url) = explode("&", $url);

Answer (score 0):

You can use the explode function () to split the string. $url = explode ( "&", $needle ) and then get the first array element.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) function, that will give you where the first occurance of a character - in your case & is in a string.  From that you can use [substr](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to retrieve the piece of the string you want.